# My ajax call of dataType jsonp goes in error section of response

Tags: jquery, jsonp

My service successfully hit but i cant handle response how to parse the jsonp data, actually i cant go in success section.

```
$.ajax({

            type : "get",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/MBPortal/kibanaCallAction.action",
            async: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'callback',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data : {institutionID: '*',requestId:e  },
            success : function(data) {
                //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log('success');
            }, error: function(data) { 
                //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                $.each(data,function(index, element){
                        // do something with the element 
                        console.log(index);
                })
                //alert(data);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What type of error you get please post error also.

Comment: In your action, do you form jsonp-callback in response ?

Comment: I do this call from kibana server to apache so that i uses dataType as jsonp . The service is hit it send response json and when i see response body in browser it display response json also .  But it goes in error section dont know why where i wrong

Comment: Can you show headers and body of your response?